# NextJs 13 Link styling

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I'm new in nextJs and for a projet, I try to create a menu with a hover effect with this code:

```
import Link from 'next/link';


const MenuItem = ({ href, label }) => (
  //This Link has a className that doesn't get styled.
  <Link href={href} className="menu-item">
    {label}
  </Link>
);

function MainNavigation() {

  return (
    <>
      <style jsx>{`
      .header {      
        height: 5rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        padding: 0 10%;
        font-family: system-ui, sans;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        font-weight: 800;
      }

      .logo {
        font-size: 2rem;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .header ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: baseline;
      }

      .header li {
        margin-left: 3rem;
      }
      
      .menu-item {
        color: #000;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .menu-item::before {
        background: hsl(45 100% 70%);
        content: "";
        inset: 0;
        position: absolute;
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transform-origin: right;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
        z-index: -1;
      }
  
      .menu-item:hover::before {
        transform: scaleX(1);
        transform-origin: left;
      }
    `}</style>

      <header className='header'>
        <div className='logo'>React Meetups</div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <MenuItem href='/' label='menu item 1' />            
            </li>
            <li>
              <MenuItem href='/' label='menu item 2' />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </>
  );
}

export default MainNavigation;
```

According nextJs 13 documentation, we don't need anymore to put in the Link the  tag but I wonder how I can do the hover effect on the menu item? Currently the style is not apply on my menu-item.

Someone could explain what's wrong in this piece of code?

Thanks

Comment: You are missing the dots before your CSS classnames.

Comment: indeed but the problem is still the same. CSS isn't apply to the menu-item

Comment: Could you please add this attribute legacyBehavior to your <Link>.

Like this -> <Link href={href} className="menu-item" legacyBehavior >
    {label}
  </Link>

Comment: still the same thing. Correct me if I'm wrong but the legacyBehavior is more to use the Link as before with the <a> and like that: ``` <Link href="/about" legacyBehavior>
      <a>About Us</a>
    </Link>```

Comment: From NextJS docs. If the child of Link is a custom component that wraps an <a> tag, you must add passHref to Link. This is necessary if you’re using libraries like styled-components. Without this, the <a> tag will not have the href attribute, which hurts your site's accessibility and might affect SEO.

Comment: But with nextJs 13, the link doesn't need anymore to wrap the <a> tag according the doc here https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13#nextlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your style

```
.header > nav > ul > li > a:hover{
/*put your CSS here*/
}
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work even if I add the <a> tag into the Link with the legacyBehavior. Actually, I don't think we have to target the <a> tag as it is not required by nextJs 13.

Comment: `.header nav ul li a:hover {
          color: red;
        }` try this

Comment: thanks it works so if I understand nextjs transform the Link to <a> tag so I have to target the rendered elem instead of the link.